# How to read/write from/to console with Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I tried recently to convert a CLI tool from JVM to native executable using Kotlin/Native. I got the following errors (which make sense):

```
> Task :compileKotlinMain FAILED
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (4, 8): Unresolved reference: java
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (5, 8): Unresolved reference: java
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (6, 8): Unresolved reference: java
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (9, 14): Unresolved reference: System
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (9, 27): Unresolved reference: System
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (12, 20): Unresolved reference: InputStream
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (12, 38): Unresolved reference: PrintStream
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (16, 57): Unresolved reference: BufferedReader
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (19, 80): Unresolved reference: PrintStream
e: C:\test1\src\main\kotlin\cli\CommandLineTool.kt: (19, 100): Unresolved reference: BufferedReader
```

What is the alternative to the Java-backed console I/O? Is there a library for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[print](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/print.html) writes its single arugment standard output.  It is overloaded method that can take `Any?` or any of the primitive types.

[readLine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) reads from standard input.  It has no arguments and returns `String?`.

These are both from the [kotlin.io](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html) package, which is an "IO API for working with files and streams".